# Proof of a limit of a function. Is it correct?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, solution-verification

Edit: There is an answer at the bottom by me explaining what is going on in this post.

Define a function $f : R \to R$ by $f(x) = 1$ if $x = 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x \ne 0$. I was attempting to prove that $\lim_{x \to 0; x\in R}f(x)$ is undefined. The following is my proof.

Proof: Suppose that $\lim_{x\to 0; x \in R}f(x)=L$. Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all those $x \in R$ for which $|x-0|<\delta$ we have that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$. But $|0| < \delta$ and by the Archimedean property we know that for $\delta > 0$ there exists an integer $n>0$ such that $0<|\frac 1 n| < \delta$. This is a contradiction, as $f(0) = 1$ and $f(\frac 1 n)= 0$ and both are less than $\delta$.

Is the proof correct?

Edit: Here a limit is defined using adherent points and not limit points. If we were to use limit points then, $\lim_{x \to 0; x\in R\setminus \{0\}}f(x)=0$. I have updated the question with correct notation.

Edit 2: Most textbooks define limits using limit points. In which case you we would have that $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0; x\in R\setminus \{0\}}f(x)$. We are considering the definition of the limit where limits are defined using adherent points. Where it really matters whether we are considering $lim_{x\to 0; x\in R\setminus \{0\}}f(x)$ or $lim_{x\to 0; x\in R}f(x)$.

Edit 3: This is the definition of convergence of a function at a point in the book Analysis 1 by Terence Tao. Let $X$ be a
subset of $R$, let $f : X → R$ be a function, let $E$ be a subset of $X$, $x_0$
be an adherent point of $E$, and let L be a real number. We say that f
converges to $L$ at $x0$ in $E$, and write $\lim_{x \to x_0;x\in E} f(x) = L$, iff $f$, after
restricting to $E$, is ε-close to $L$ near $x_0$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. If $f$ does not
converge to any number $L$ at $x_0$, we say that $f$ diverges at $x0$, and leave
$\lim_{x\to x_0;x\in E} f(x)$ undefined.
In other words, we have $lim_{x\to x_0;x\in E} f(x) = L$ iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$,
there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) − L| ≤ ε$ for all $x \in E$ such that
$|x − x0| < \delta$.

There are a two other things he defines that are used in this definition. That of $\varepsilon$ closeness and local $\varepsilon$ closeness. For those wanting to read those, [Here is the link](https://lms.umb.sk/pluginfile.php/111477/mod_page/content/5/TerenceTao_Analysis.I.Third.Edition.pdf). It is on page 221.

Edit 4: It might be useless defining limits without limit points. But that is the definition for which I am trying to prove this.

Comment: The limit does exist

Comment: @eipim1 Only when $0$ is a limit point. It does not exist when $0$ is an adherent point.

Comment: In taking a limit, you do not consider the point $0$ itself

Comment: @FShrike Most textbooks define limits using limit points. In which case you are right that we would not consider $0$ if $0$ was a limit point. But the definition for limits using adherent points, it really matters whether $0$ is a limit point or an adherent point. You can get two different answers.

Comment: (continuing comments on an answer that's been deleted): I've read the comments. Please learn the definition! It's in any calculus book, no need to worry about all the issues above. The _definition_ **is** "$0<|x|\delta$ implies", and you saying you're "considering" one thing and not considering something else does not change the definition. In particular the limit _does_ exist. You can try to understand that, or if you prefer you can continue to insist that the limit does not exist. But is _does_, regardless

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The limit does not exist when $x \in R$. This was an example in the book Analysis 1 by Terence Tao. [Here is the link](https://lms.umb.sk/pluginfile.php/111477/mod_page/content/5/TerenceTao_Analysis.I.Third.Edition.pdf). Please read the last remark on page 221 and continue reading it until page 222 to understand what is going on here.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I believe Tao is trying to impart what goes wrong if we carelessly give a definition for limit. Considering this exchange, I believe he has succeeded with flying colours :)

Comment: @AlvinL if by your comment you mean that I’m misunderstanding the definition. Tao used the definition of an adherent point for the whole chapter and only switches to limit points when discussing differentiation. I have learnt that it is not standard to use this definition and to stick to the definition concerning limit points. He explicitly states that he’s using the definition where we are considering when a point can be an adherent point without being a limit point. If you didn’t mean that, just disregard this comment. I might have just read your comment in the wrong tone.

Comment: @Seeker His definition of continuity coincides with the usual one, because there is no difference between the standard and nonstandard definitions for limits in case of continuous functions. He has to use the limit point variant for derivatives, because otherwise he would be dividing by zero.

Comment: @AlvinL I have learnt that it is only useful to use limit points in the definition of a limit. It was just for that specific example that this whole thing started. I don’t believe there is any point in discussing this topic anymore. Thanks for all your input on this post!

Answer (score 1):

Taking absolute value of positive number os nothing but wasting time!

How you get contradiction from $0<\frac {1} {n} < \delta$ and $f(0) =1$ ?

$1=f(0) <f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ is not true unless $f$ is increasing. In fact $f$ is decreasing on $[0, \infty) $

But choosing $0<\epsilon<1$ , you can produce a contradiction. You have to mention that in your proof as this the most crucial step.

(The way you defined limit)

Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ , then $\exists \delta>0$ such that $|x|<\delta \implies  |f(x) -L|<\frac{1}{2}$

For $x=0, |1 -L|<\frac{1}{2}\implies L\in (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}) $

For $x=\frac{1}{N}$ (obtained by Archimedean property) , $|L|<\frac{1}{2}$ i.e $L\in (-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) $

Implies $L\in (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}) \cap (-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) =\emptyset$ (impossible)

Such $L\in\Bbb{R}$ doesn't exists.

But this is not the correct definition of Limit.

Def:

$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) =L$ if $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $ \forall x\in \Bbb{R} , 0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies $|f(x) -L|<\epsilon$

Comment: I also showed that such a value of L cannot exist as we get two different values. Although I didn’t state that explicitly. Is my proof correct?

Comment: I should have specified in the question that the contradiction I got was that for every  $\varepsilon > 0$ there does not exist a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$. The contradiction was that we found two numbers which are less than $\delta$ and both give different values. So there can't be a $\delta$, because we can always find a smaller number than $\delta$ that is greater than $0$ for which we would get two different answers.

Comment: But choosing $0<\epsilon<1$ , you can produce a contradiction. You have to mention that in your proof as this the most crucial step.

Comment: Yes, your proof does look more rigorous. I agree that would have been a better approach. But the contradiction that we get two different values that are not equal to each other is also valid. As then there is no single number that is the limit of the function. But I agree that your proof is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

> Proof: Suppose that $\lim_{x\to 0; x \in R}f(x)=L$. Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all those $x \in R$ for which $|x-0|<\delta$ we have that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$. But $|0| < \delta$ and by the Archimedean property we know that for $\delta > 0$ there exists an integer $n>0$ such that $0<|\frac 1 n| < \delta$. This is a contradiction, as $f(0) = 1$ and $f(\frac 1 n)= 0$ and both are less than $\delta$.

It's not clear what you are contradicting with. We assume the limit is $L$. Taking $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{5}$, for instance, it should hold that for some $\delta>0$
$$ L-\frac{1}{5} < f(x) < L+\frac{1}{5} $$
for any $x\in (-\delta,\delta)$. In particular, for sufficiently large $N$,
$$ -\frac{1}{5} < 1-L < \frac{1}{5} \quad\mbox{and}\quad -\frac{1}{5} < f(1/N)-L = -L < \frac{1}{5} $$
and that does lead to contradiction. You should write it out.

Furthermore, in your argument, you don't mention what $\varepsilon$ is. It could be $\varepsilon = 100$. I don't see how you arrive at a contradiction.

---

Alternatively,

Use Proposition 9.3.9. Take the constant sequence $x_n = 0$ for every $n$. Then $f(x_n) \to 1$. For another sequence, $x_n = 1/n$, for instance, $f(x_n) \to 0$. So $\lim _{x\to 0, x\in\mathbb R} f(x)$ does not exist.

---

This sort of definition for limit is nonstandard. Mainly because it makes the existence of the limit depend on a specific point. It's very dangerous to define it like this. It's not even clear if it is a well defined concept.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. But I would like to know if my proof is correct or not?

Comment: The contradiction was that we get two values. Namely 1 and 0. Because $f(0) = 1$ and for a number $0<n < \delta$, $f(n) = 1$. And both $n$ and $0$ are less than $\delta$.

Comment: Getting ahead of yourself. You assumed the limit was $L$. Your argument must contain this data.

Comment: I agree that the definition is not standard. Even Tao specifies that. But the problem was regarding this definition. I should have specified everything from the beginning.

Comment: It was supposed to be a proof by contradiction. It does use that hypothesis but I didn’t specify that explicitly. My bad on that one.

Comment: @Seeker Your initial protest regarding limit points and adherent points makes no sense, still. Tao also emphasises that it is not reasonable to define a limit at a nonadherent point. And it's not like limit points and adherent points are excluding one another.

Comment: I agree the initial comments were not correct. I should have stated the question specifying that we are considering points even when they are adherent points and don’t necessarily have to limit points. Then the limit is undefined at $0$.   And I know that $0$ Is also a limit point of $R$.

Answer (score 0):

Tao defines limits using adherent points and not limit points. My previous comments regarding the use of adherent points and limit points throughout this post are completely wrong as I didn’t understand it too well myself at the time either.

But now that I do, here is what is going on in this post. Tao mentions that this is a general definition(a user also commented saying that there are two competing definitions of limits of functions. Unfortunately the answer that comment was under has been deleted. But I think some users with a lot of reputation can still see deleted answers?). He defines a limit as follows(paraphrasing because he used a few simpler concepts to help understand the definition).

Definition: Let $X$ be a subset of $R$. Let $f:X\to R$ be a function. Let $E$ be a subset of $X$. Let $x_0$ be an adherent point of $E$. Let $L$ be a real number. We say that $f$ converges to $L$ near $x_0$ and write $$\lim_{x\to x_0;x\in E}f(x)=L$$ if for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that for all those values of $x\in E$ for which $|x-x_0|<\delta$, we have that $|f(x) - L|<\varepsilon$.

Notice the Specification under the limit sign that $x\in E$. He then remarks that most authors define a limit using limit points. Which in the above notation of a limit would become $$\lim_{x\to x_0;x\in E\setminus \{x_0\}}f(x)=L $$

Notice the specification that $x\in E\setminus \{x_0\}$.

Now to my post, I originally asked if the following limit diverges. $$\lim_{x\to 0;x\in R}f(x) $$ Here we are working with adherent points. In the sense that $x$ can take on the value $0$. Notice the specification that $x\in R$.

This was the first example after defining the limit of a function given by Tao as to what happens to limits if consider $x_0$ to be an adherent point(meaning that we consider the limit $$\lim_{x\to x_0;x\in E}f(x) $$) or a limit point(meaning that we consider the limit $$\lim_{x\to x_0;x\in E\setminus \{x_0\}}f(x) $$). If we consider $0$ above to be a limit point, meaning that we consider the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0;x\in R\setminus \{0\}}f(x)$$ Then that limit converges to $1$. But if we consider $0$ to be an adherent point, meaning that we consider the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0;x\in R}f(x)$$ then the limit is undefined.

As you probably have figured out by now, saying adherent point and limit point when describing whether the value of $x\in E$ or $x\in E\setminus \{x_0\}$ is confusing as limit points are also adherent points. Although, once you get it, it’s clear what it means.

At the time I did not understand this, but then eventually I did. I though I should type up an explanation for the whole confusion I caused that day to others and myself.